# How can we choose which model generalizes better?

Tags: error

I got asked this question today:

> How could we reasonably safely conclude that, for a given dataset, in practice, one classifier generalizes better than another?

I could not give a concise answer, and thought maybe you guys would like to chip in. I understand obviously that there is still much in terms of research in this area that needs to be done, however it I think its still worth an attempted answer.

Comment: I think internal (? external) validation methods attempt to address this?

Comment: @charles this should have been an answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Increased certainty comes with independent validation against new sample. Internal validation methods might increase probability that you are not going to make radical errors but still they use same data for which model parameters were optimized first.

This is reason why model scoring against new data and comparison against actuals produces better idead about behaviour of your model in production use.